# How can i add rules to a list in python

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

I basicly need to be able to restrict the items that can be appended in a list. Just like in a solitaire game, i need an item to be added to a list if it is meant to follow that item alphabetically and if it doesnt then an error is returned. for instance; letter d can be appended in front of letter c, if its a different letter or in the wrong order then the card wont be moved.

the code below is the best i can do so far.

```
a = ['a','c','e','j','h']

b = ['b','d','f','i','g']

def list_a():

    loop = 0
    choice = 0

    while loop == 1:
        print('''Choose from one of the following options:
                    1. Move item from list b to list a
                    2. add item to list a!''')

        choice = int(input("What would you like to do?: "))
        if choice == 1:
            move_item()

        elif choice == 2:
            add_item()
    return choice

    print('List a: ',a)
    print('List b: ',b)




def move_item():
    loop = 0
    choice = 0

    while loop == 1:
        print('''Choose from one of the following options:
                    1. Move item 1
                    2. move item 2
                    3. Move item 3
                    4. move item 4
                    5. Move item 5!''')

        choice = int(input("What would you like to do?: "))
        if choice == 1:
            a.append(b.pop(0))

        elif choice == 2:
            a.append(b.pop(1))

        elif choice == 3:
            a.append(b.pop(2))

        elif choice == 4:
            a.append(b.pop(3))

        elif choice == 5:
            a.append(b.pop())

    return choice

def add_item():
    print()

list_a()
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Also, why not just subclass list?

Comment: looks like homework to me! It's to trivial to even look past the headline!

Comment: Several issues with your code & question. For code: were do you check for empty/unacceptable input. E.g., if I type `asdf` into the first prompt, `choice` will be `0` (if it could even enter the infinite loop in the first place, since you're not incrementing/changing loop).

Comment: Also, __NO__ idea what you mean when you say d can be appended before c, since append means "add to the end", not "insert before".

Comment: Wish I could cast a close vote; based on your previous history, you clearly need more time to get to know Python before posting on SO.

Comment: @Edwin; i thought the purpose of stack overflow is to ask people when you are stack and u dont know what to do. What would be the point of me coming on here if i already know python apart from helping out other people in need.

Comment: Yes, that is SO's purpose. However, most people on here have a firm grasp of programming constructs and some measure of experience in the language (e.g., I/O, file ops, etc.) before they ask here. Unfortunately, until you can fix some of the basic problems in your code here, such as your infinite loops, without thinking about it twice, you'll probably have to tag your posts with the [homework] tag to get better and more thorough responses from the SO community.

Comment: I think it's fair game to post relatively beginner questions on SO - if you don't want to answer them, just leave them for someone else. But if it is homework, please do tag it, to remind people not to hand you a canned solution.

Comment: @Edwin That is both false and rude.  While the way this question is asked needs some improvement, scaring away beginners from either the language or SO helps nobody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass of list and override **setitem**, insert, and/or whatever else you need to to store your business logic.

```
class MyList(list):
  def passes_rules(self, idx, value):
    """ Checks to see if this value can be set to this index """

  def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
    if self.passes_rules(idx, value):
      super(MyList, self).__setitem__(idx, value)
```

Somebody else could probably tell us if **setitem** is sufficient, or if you need to worry about append and insert, also. Experimentation would work, too, but let me know what you find. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can test for whether `letter1` comes before `letter2` in the alphabet with something like this.

```
import string
if string.ascii_lowercase.find(letter1) < string.ascii_lowercase.find(letter2):
    print("Letter 1 comes before letter 2")
```

Comment: Letters can be compared directly, e.g. the expression `'a' < 'b'` is true.